# Psychopy: update - code needs to be fixed

Tags: psychopy

I'm running an experiment using psychopy for my bachelor thesis. The experiment was set up last year (08/2014) using the BuilderView. After an update to the newest version of psychopy 1.82.01 a code I was using isn't working anymore. The code perfectly functioned unter 1.81.03. 
The aim of this code was to remember an initial rating and using this rating as a starting point for a second rating. That means in a new routine you could adjust your initial rating. 
The code I was using is:

**Begin Routine:
rating3.setMarkerPos(rating.getRating())**

Does anyone know how to fix this code? 
Thanks a lot! 
Julie

Comment: What do you mean by "isn't working"? Please include the error message or describe the incorrect behavior you are seeing.

Comment: File "N:\ ....", line 1292, in <module>
win.flip()
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\PsychoPy2\lib\site-packages\psychopy-1.82.01-py2.7egg\psychopy\visual\window.py",line 539, in flip
 thisStim.draw()
File"C:\Program Files
(x86)\PsychoPy2\lib\site-packages\psychopy-1.82.01-py2.7.egg\psychopy\visual\ratingscale.py", line 981, in draw
proportion = self.markerPlacedAt/ self.tickMarks
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'NoneType' and 'float'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what changed with the new version. For me your general approach mostly works (no crash, but not always the right position).

I used two default rating scales, in two different routines. The second one has a code component, and its important that the code component comes **after** the rating component within that routine (appearing lower on the screen in the routine panel). The code in Begin routine is:

```
rating_2.setMarkerPos(rating.getRating() - rating.low)
```

The error message you were getting is almost certainly because the `rating.getRating()` was returning `None`. That could happen if there was no response (e.g., if `allowSkip` was `True` and the participant skipped, or no rating had been given and your code proceeded anyway for some other reason, perhaps a time-out).

Subtracting rating.low is only needed if your ratings do not start at 0.